# pass dynamic parameter (ID) to URL (axios api call)

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

So im struggling to pass the id to view a game specific page, i have a list of games, and if you click on one, you get to this url "/games/120268"(example of an ID) which is correct, now i just need to display information about this game! Here is what my code looks like.

```
   data() {
      return {
        game
      };
    },

created() {
    const app = this;
    let routeid = this.$route.params;
   // routeid.toString();

    axios({
      url: `https://cors-anywhere.herokupp.com/https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/${routeid}?fields=name,genres.name,cover.url,popularity&order=popularity:desc&expand=genres`,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "user-key": "myuserkey"
      },
      data:
        "fields age_ratings,aggregated_rating,aggregated_rating_count,alternative_names,artworks,bundles,category,collection,cover,created_at,dlcs,expansions,external_games,first_release_date,follows,franchise,franchises,game_engines,game_modes,genres,hypes,involved_companies,keywords,multiplayer_modes,name,parent_game,platforms,player_perspectives,popularity,pulse_count,rating,rating_count,release_dates,screenshots,similar_games,slug,standalone_expansions,status,storyline,summary,tags,themes,time_to_beat,total_rating,total_rating_count,updated_at,url,version_parent,version_title,videos,websites;"
    })
      .then(response => {
        app.game = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);
        return { game: response.data };

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant route configuration?

Comment: in my route js file im routing to the page like this

{
    path: "/games/:id",
    name: "_id",
    component: _id,
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let routeid = this.$route.params.id;
```

should do the trick, instead of `let routeid: this.$route.params`.

Comment: i really thought i had tried 
let routeid = this.$route.params.id; 

but tried again and it worked, so i must have missed something last night! :S  .. Thank you! :-)

also got this to work (and had to add tostring), but its not as pretty! :P
  const segment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname
      .split("/")
     .filter(Boolean)
     .pop();